# Can I run Java or .NET apps on a Windows 8.1 tablet?

Tags: windows-8.1, tablet

I've only owned iOS and Android tablets but I am thinking about getting a sub-$200 Windows 8.1 tablet.  Mostly for eBay and browsing.

But, being a .NET (and Java) developer, I'm interested in running my custom applications on it.

Forgive me if this isn't the correct place to ask this but I couldn't find a "Microsoft" site on SE.

Anyway, my questions are:

1) Can I just copy my .NET (2.0+) applications over and run them?

2) Assuming I can run "normal" .NET, do I have to use Metro applications or would Winforms, MVC, etc. run as well?

3) Can I run Java applications?  Mostly applications built with Tomcat and Spring MVC.

4) Can I play Minecraft??   :-)  That's a bonus question.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the down vote?  Is this not relevant?

Comment: I searched, but did not find it.  Also, never had a Windows tablet.  Nor have I followed it much (or any tablet).  So I didn't know there were ARM versions.

Comment: @Ramhound -- Would you care to share your search terms?  I searched for "can I run .net on windows tablets" and found ONE question (not counting mine).  "windows 8.1 tablet run java" returns NOTHING (except mine).  "windows 8.1 tablet java" returns NOTHING (except mine).  "windows tablet java" returned ONE question that was not relevant.  So I *did* search.  "Tablet" tag only show ~210 questions.  "Windows-tabletpc" ~21.  So, I'm curious what you used to find those vast number of "already asked" questions.

Comment: Again, can you please share HOW you found those "related" questions?  I would have looked there first if I could figure out how to find such related questions.  If not, then I am being penalized, given the answer, but not told how the answer was determined.

Comment: I will not.  Good luck!

Comment: More hypocritical actions from this family of sites...big surprise there.

Comment: It's actually just the way you asked me

Comment: That makes no logical sense.  But fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an Intel 8.1 tablet (not an RT tablet), then you can run basically anything x86 on it, assuming performance, screen size, finger touch input, etc. are all acceptable.

I've run many different things on x86 Windows tablets, including desktop VLC, the Tor Browser bundle, and the PC version of the DirecTV Genie app, all with success.

Basically, the fact it's on a tablet doesn't change that it's an x86 Windows PC, just with the tablet form factor.  You can look at this as good (my apps run!) or bad (these apps I'm running don't work well in this form factor), but either way, they run.